# Erro ao emular app pelo Android

Tags: android, emulador

Eu estou a fazer uma *SplashScreen* a partir deste [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZZkanr8tS6w). Depois de "concluir" o que o tutorial diz e ao tentar emular o *App*, um **ERRO** aparece-me e me frustra.

Sendo ele:

> 09/13 01:19:32: Launching app $ adb shell am start -n
>   "hyanhythalo.skyroxterror/hyanhythalo.skyroxterror.SplashScreen" -a
>   android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER Error
>   while executing: am start -n
>   "hyanhythalo.skyroxterror/hyanhythalo.skyroxterror.SplashScreen" -a
>   android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
>   Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN
>   cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER]
>   cmp=hyanhythalo.skyroxterror/.SplashScreen }
>
> Error while Launching activity

Comment: Como está seu AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Tentou implantar o *.apk* diretamente e ver o logcat?